# Bring or go down 26,000 feet or by 26,000 feet

Tags: word-usage

If someone asks someone to decrease the height (plane)  what is a natural way to describe that?

> Bring the plane down by 26,000 feet.
>
> Go down by 26,000 feet.

And can "by" be dropped?

> Go down 26,000 feet.

What is the shortest and most natural way to express this according to you other than my sentences?

Answer (score -2):

Probably the most common expressions would be "descend", "reduce altitude", or (less formally) "drop".  However, a pilot would be unlikely to be told to reduce altitude by some *amount*, because this is potentially unsafe.  Instead, routinely, they are told the target altitude:

> Reduce altitude **to 15,000 feet**.
>
> OK, we're 300 miles from our destination.  **Descend to 15,000** (feet) and prepare for landing.

But this just applies to general communication.  Actual pilots and air traffic controllers use a specialized language to prevent misunderstanding.  There are many resources about this on the internet, or check the [Aviation Stack Exchange](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/).

In any case, I'm not saying that a pilot would never be asked to "descend" by some amount.  It's possible that student pilots are required to do this as part of their training, to see if they can quickly and precisely calculate what the new altitude should be.

Rather, I'm saying it's unsafe, because it's easy to confuse a request to reduce altitude *by* some amount with a request to reduce altitude *to* some target.  A target is easier to understand, because it requires no calculation. You can easily read the current altitude on the altimeter, and go up or down accordingly.

Comment: How about *descend* as another possibility?  It's more concise than "reduce altitude" and more formal than "drop".

Comment: @NateEldredge  Er, yeah.  That too.  Thanks for reminding me  :)

Comment: -1; the standard terminology used in aviation is "to descend." This is the word used by pilots and air traffic controllers. "To drop" refers to a sudden and likely uncontrolled loss of altitude. The assertion that verbal commands are no longer used is also incorrect, and the full story about "flight levels" is not properly represented here. For better info on the aviation aspects, the reader should head over to the excellent Aviation Stack Exchange.

Comment: @TypeIA  I've already edited my answer, but rather than reflexively downvoting, why not give me a chance to edit my answer to your satisfaction?  What would you suggest?

Comment: I will gladly reverse my vote if the answer is improved. That's how the vote system is supposed to work :) "Reduce altitude" is not standard pilot/controller terminology, and I would suggest removing the "information" about ATC data links and flight levels completely as these are off topic and the OP didn't ask about them. Referring to Aviation SE or other resources would be good.

Comment: You are quite correct, at least, that pilots and controllers _always_ refer to absolute altitudes and never relative changes in altitude.

Comment: @TypeIA  edited.

Comment: And will "drop" be used this way in the sentence: "Drop to 15,000." Or should it be "Drop 15,000."  Does the second sentence sound like the amount by which the plane was dropped? "

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish  News stories and other descriptions will commonly talk about planes gaining or losing some amount of altitude.  It's just commands to change altitude that use absolute values.  Otherwise you will see statements such as this BBC headline:  *"Plane **drops** 500ft in 18 seconds after error"*

Comment: I meant actual commands.  So what will be an informal word for "ascending"?  And what do you think about: " Go down to" Or "Go up to"?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish  If you're talking about the actual commands a pilot would receive, then **ascend** and **descend** are most likely.  Pilots don't normally use "informal" words when talking about how to fly the airplane.   They use the same words every time, to avoid miscommunication.